# How remove decimal part from string?

Tags: c#

how to trim decimal part in given string of a decimal value in C#. im getting  20472.060 desired o/p - 20472

```
decimal totalamountWithTaxes = pri + result1 + result2 ;          
string totalAmountPlusTaxes = totalamountWithTaxes.ToString();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
int number = (int) totalAmountPlusTaxes;
```

or

```
string totalAmountPlusTaxes = String.Format("{0:C0}",totalamountWithTaxes);
```

Comment: i need in string only

Comment: @krishnamohan:- Updated the answer!

Comment: Also, another alternative is using `totalamountWithTaxes.ToString("C0")`.

Comment: int  totalamountWithTaxesAsInt = (int)(pri + result1 + result2);

Answer (score 2):

Int32 Amount = Convert.ToInt32(totalamountWithTaxes.ToString().Substring(0,totalamountWithTaxes.ToString().IndexOf(".")));

Comment: This is too unnecessary and the codes not clean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the above example is right and also I recommend you to visit:
[String.Format Method-MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)